# Серелизация объектов в WCF

Tags: c#, serialize, .net, wcf

Всем привет. Имеется сервис, который отдает `JSON`.
Допустим, есть вот такой дата контракт

```
[DataContract]
public class User
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name", Order = 0)]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "values", Order = 1)]
    public AjaxDictionary<string, string> Values { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class AjaxDictionary<Tk, Tv> : ISerializable 
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _Dictionary;
    public AjaxDictionary()
    {
        _Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public AjaxDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
    {
        _Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> d in dictionary)
        {
            _Dictionary.Add(d.Key,d.Value);
        }

    }

    public AjaxDictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        _Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get { return _Dictionary[key]; }
        set { _Dictionary[key] = value; }
    }

    public void Add(string key, string value)
    {
        _Dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        foreach (string key in _Dictionary.Keys)
            info.AddValue(XmlConvert.DecodeName(key), _Dictionary[key]);
    }
}
```

}

и собственно сам сервис

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/getInfo", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public User GetItemsInfo(){

   var user = new User();
   user.Name = "Пользователь";
   var userValues = new AjaxDictionary<string, string>();
   userValues.Add("registration address", "Пензенский жд вокзал");
   userValues.Add("marital status", "холост");
   user.Values = userValues;
   return user;
}
```

В результате всех этих действий, получается вот такой JSON объект.

```
{
  "name": "Пользователь",
  "values": {
              "registration_x0020_address": "Пензенский жд вокзал",
              "marital_x0020_status": "холост"
            }
}
```

Как видно, в получившемся JSON объекте, за место символа пробела, подставился его код *x0020*. Как избежать этого при серелизации объекта?

Comment: А что возвращает `XmlConvert.DecodeName` для ваших ключей? Проверьте вручную.

Comment: Он возвратил ключ с некорректными пробелами. В общем решил проблему. Сначала хотел переписать стандартный сериализатор wcf, но это слишком геморно. А потом наткнулся вот на это http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078397/returning-raw-json-string-in-wcf

Comment: Зачем вы используете свою реализацию словаря и чем не подошла стандартная?

Answer (score 1):

То место, где вы хотите оставить пробелы - это практически имена переменных в javascript (JavaScript Object Notation). С пробелами они быть не могут. Попробуйте переоформить ответ сервера, например в таком ключе:

```
return Json(new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"some key 1 with spaces","value 1"},
                {"some key 2 with spaces","value 2"},
                {"some key 3 with spaces","value 3"},
            }.ToArray());
```

JSON:

```
[{"Key":"some key 1 with spaces","Value":"value 1"},
{"Key":"some key 2 with spaces","Value":"value 2"},
{"Key":"some key 3 with spaces","Value":"value 3"}]
```